# How to read resource in scala project when deployed in docker

Tags: scala, docker, sbt

im new to scala and sbt and im building a project and reading a model file (.h5) using the `org.nd4j.linalg.io.ClassPathResource` class. The h5 file is located under the resources folder and it works well when running the project locally using Intelij.
However, when the app runs on the docker i get the following error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [scala/Product.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

when i print the path which the app looking for i see that it is the root of my jar(when local), and root root folder of the machine in the docker environment.

i understand that whatever runs my app in the docker can't access the resources inside my jar.
My question is how do i use resources without changing the code before i deployment.

I have tried adding the following to the build.sbt file

```
mappings.in(Universal) += {((baseDirectory.value / "main" / "resources" / "my_model.h5"), "my_model.h5")}
```

Comment: Ddi you tried creating an assembly jar which includes its resources within it.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez do you mean the following line in settings ?   resourceDirectory in Universal := baseDirectory.value / "main" / "resources"

Comment: I mean using [this](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin.Or you may tell us which one are you using to build your docker image, maybe the **sbt-native-packager**?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Im using the *sbt-native-packager* but haven't manage to make it work for me. If you are familiar with the first one, i will be more than glad to understand how to pull if off

Comment: I would recommend you to ask [here](https://gitter.im/sbt/sbt-native-packager).

Comment: now i get the following error where i try to find the resource: